# How to use v-select to search for entries and also use the input field to type in text for the search?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

In a `v-select` field, I would like to display entries in a fold-out manner on the one hand, and on the other hand, I would like to use the field to be able to enter a text in order to search for the corresponding item among the entries. Is there any prop in vuetify that I can use or something like that. Or is there a good tip to implement the text field?

```
<v-select
  v-model="searchParams.importApples"
  label="Importapples"
  :items="importApplesItems"
  :menu-props="{ bottom: true, offsetY: true }"
  item-text="label"
  item-value="value"
  filterable
  clearable
  outlined
  dense
/>
```

Comment: Have you looked at `v-autocomplete`? https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes/

Comment: It nailed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The usage of autocomplete solved my problem.